# How to make a variable that is accesible to React component and needs asyncronous data to be useful?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I understand how to pass data from component to component using `this.props`.

However, I can't seem to figure out a way to pass values or gather values asynchronously from say a database to a variable that will be used throughout the component,
I can't change this variable after load it has to be loaded before the render method since it is not allowed to be changed once loaded.

What I mean is this attempt 1

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

let my_variable = "";
fetch("url", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({})
})
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(result => {
    return (my_variable = result);
  });


--------------------new way-------------------------
const my_variable = fetch("url", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({})
})
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(result => {
    return (result);
  });
-------------------------------------------------

class MyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <NewElement variableNeeded={my_variable} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default MyClass;
```

It, of course, does not work since the empty variable hits the component and the cannot be updated.

Option B:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class MyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <NewElement variableNeeded={this.props.my_variable} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
export default MyClass;
```

Again does not work, this class is a child of another class and the variable value was gathered inside the onComponentDidMount() the render method was hit first so I don't know how to gather the data then pass it.

If anyone could help me with this I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Use `this.state`

Comment: this.state work sorry but I dont want it to attempt to refresh on every render. How to make sure to call  outside of a component’s render such as in method one

Comment: Make the api requirest in `componentDidMount()`

Comment: Sorry to everyone I just needed to assign my variable to the fetch result rather than inside the return of fetch. I have edited version 1

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the data:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('url', /* your config here */).then(data => {
        return data.json();
    }).then(json => {
        this.setState({ variable: json });
    });
}
```

... Then in the `render` method ...

```
render() {
    const { variable } = this.state;

    return (
        <>
            { variable && <NewElement variableNeeded={variable} /> }
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for handling gathering asynchronously data from somewhere you need to use React Life Cycles like so :

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      variable: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("url", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({})
    })
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(result => {
        return this.setState({ variable: result });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <>{variable && <NewElement variableNeeded={variable} />}</>;
  }
}

export default MyClass;
```

Comment: It works but is there a way to do it outside the render method? like in method one?

Comment: if you want to fetch some data for your component this is the standard way but you can use redux too

Comment: ok, I have not implemented redux in the app but I sure need to get to that. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is ok also but now I don't get the message from the component that it is being re-rendered, using method A and change the top part to the following

```
--------------------new way-------------------------
const my_variable = fetch("url", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({})
})
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(result => {
    return (result);
  });
-------------------------------------------------
```